# Manipulating lsof outputs

Tags: lsof

I would like to write a list of files opened for read or write to fileX.txt including **only** the pathname of each file in the output. Here is my command:`lsof / -FDu >> fileX.txt`
When I checked the contents of fileX.txt, it contains more information than I want on each output. How can I manipulate my output to be **only** the pathname of each output?

Comment: I assume by "pathname" you actually mean filename?

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't have this the wrong way? Your command throws `lsof: status error on -FDu: No such file or directory`. You probably want `lsof -FDu /`.

Comment: Thanks, Panki but no! '$ lsof -FDu /' displays some wired output. My initial command is to what I meant because I get seemingly meaningful output albeit more information than I want. The issue is that I need a way to extract only the path of the files displayed.

Comment: Your command makes no sense. `lsof / -FDu` will print info about the files named `/` and `-FDu`. `lsof -FDu` (as suggested by panki) will ask it to print info about `/` in a special format "suitable for other programs" (the `-F` flag), but including only the file type (by default), the major/minor number (`D`) and user the id (`u`). Have you simply copy-pasted that from somewhere and expected it to work, because why?

Comment: If you want a list of all the opened files, one per line, then ask that Q directly and specify what should happen with 1. paths containing *newlines* 2. paths which are not accessible (they're hidden by a mount, inside a separate namespace, they were removed, etc). 3. sockets, pipes and other files which have no paths.

Comment: If you don't care about any of that and just want a list of paths (no matter if it's garbage), then simply `lsof -Fn | sed -n 's,^n/,/,p' | sort -u` will do.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you could try piping your output through awk, like so:

```
lsof / -FDu | awk '{print $9}' | grep -Ev '/$'
```

The awk command is to isolate the path column and the grep part is to eliminate the lines that just have '/'  with trailing space after them.